# Change the order of entries

Tags: text-processing, latex

I have a file full of the following entries similar to the following:

```
`\index{a!b!c} \index{small!medium!large} \index{mouse!dog!elephant}`
```

I need a script so that all of these are changed so that:

```
\index{c!b!a} \index{large!medium!small} \index{elephant!dog!mouse}
```

Basically what happened is that I created index entries for a LaTex file and I got the order for the index entries backwards. There has to be a script that can fix this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follows with `Perl`:

```
perl -lpe 's|\\index\{\K.*?(?=\})|join "!", reverse split "!", $&|eg'
```

Brief explanation :

- select into capture brackets the portion on left of whose lies `\index{`  and the nearest closing `}` to the right.
- split on bang, rearrange the split parts, and rejoin with bang.
- repeat this on the line as many times such a combo is found.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I shall reflect it in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: There's s reason why i chose `q[!]` over `"!"`  as its seen bash bang inside double quotes acts like csh.

Comment: But here, from the POV of `bash`, the `!` is inside single quotes. It would help with `csh` where `!` is still a problem inside single quotes, but `!"` doesn't trigger history expansion while `!]` does.

Comment: Hmm , yup that's right  I overlooked that. Incorporating that as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `awk` as follows:

```
echo '\index{a!b!c} \index{small!medium!large} \index{mouse!dog!elephant}' | awk '{ print gensub(/\{([^!]*)!([^!]*)!([^!]*)\}/,"{\\3!\\2!\\1}", "g") }'

\index{c!b!a} \index{large!medium!small} \index{elephant!dog!mouse}
```

or `perl`

```
perl -n -p -e ' s#(\\index\{)([^!]+)\!([^!]+)\!([^!]+)\}#$1$4\!$3\!$2\}#g'
\index{c!b!a} \index{large!medium!small} \index{elephant!dog!mouse}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -E 's/\{([^!]*)!([^!]*)!([^}]*)}/{\3!\2!\1\}/g'
```

Example:

```
$ var='\index{a!b!c} \index{small!medium!large} \index{mouse!dog!elephant}'
$ echo "$var" | sed -E 's/\{([^!]*)!([^!]*)!([^}]*)}/{\3!\2!\1\}/g'
\index{c!b!a} \index{large!medium!small} \index{elephant!dog!mouse}
```